# Cant mount my hard drive in rescue mode

Tags: mount, hard-drive, unmount

When I try to mount one of my hard drives, it can't locate the folder with the hard drive.

This is the output for the command `df`:

```
Filesystem                       1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                            33000428    119124  32881304   1% /
none                              33000428    119124  32881304   1% /
198.27.85.63:/home/pub/rescue.v7 886788312 250295096 591423904  30% /nfs
198.27.85.63:/home/pub/pro-power 886788312 250295096 591423904  30% /power
198.27.85.63:/home/pub/commonnfs 886788312 250295096 591423904  30% /common
tmpfs                                10240       204     10036   2% /dev
tmpfs                              6600088        72   6600016   1% /run
tmpfs                                 5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                             13200160         0  13200160   0% /run/shm
```

This comes when I run the command `fdisk -l`:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/md3: 1978.9 GB, 1978886193152 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 483126512 cylinders, total 3865012096 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 21.0 GB, 20970405888 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5119728 cylinders, total 40957824 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

When I try to mount the `/dev/sda1` hard drive with the command `mount -o barrier=0 /dev/sda1` it gives me this message:

```
mount: can't find /dev/sda1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

How can i fix this, so i can backup all of my stuff?

This comes when I try to mount /dev/sdb3:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

Then I tried to use the command `mdadm --assemble --run /mnt /dev/sdb3` but then it just gives me this:

```
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 is busy - skipping
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since sda1 is not in fstab, you must specify the mountpoint, e.g.

```
mount -o barrier=0 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

then you will be able to find your files in /mnt.